# ABRT enabled and application core dumps?

Tags: linux, core-dump, abrt

ABRT is running on a RHEL7 server, so the kernel conf is :

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e %P %I
```

All core dumps from application systems/installed packages are located in (default behavior) : `/var/spool/abrt`.

Problem is, when a custom application started by a user crashes, a core dump is generated at the location where the user started it and all the time there is not enough space (generally in user home) to store the dump.

My question is, how can I change the core dump location for these kind of applications without changing ABRT functioning?

I was about to rewrite `core_pattern` to a user directory but I guess ABRT will write all system core dumps in it too, right?

So what is the solution?

Comment: You could disable those coredump from the users - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893299/how-to-get-a-coredump-from-abrt.

Comment: Possible dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/how-to-set-the-core-dump-file-location-and-name.

Comment: for system applications there's no problem with abrt location, but with user applications there is one because when a dump is generated the location is the directory where the user launched his application (and not abrt dir).
What I want is to configure core dump location in a specific directory but only for user applications (not system). If I change core_pattern to a specific directory reachable by users, does abrt will store his core dumps too?

Comment: `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/var/crash/core.%u.%e.%p` - https://linux-audit.com/understand-and-configure-core-dumps-work-on-linux/. I would still contend that you want them off for users, by default, and they can enable it via `limits` per program if they do in fact need them. When they enable it they can decide where to run the app and make sure it's from a dir that has enough space to deal w/ it.