# How to change core dump location without sudo

Tags: linux, non-root-user, core-dump

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)

My program is crashing, and generating a core dump.  Unfortunately, it's trying to dump it in my home directory, which doesn't come close to having the space to hold it:

BFD: Warning: core.30906 is truncated: expected core file size >= 155732344832, found: 29430394880.

I need to set things so that when I launch my program, any core dump will go to a location I specify, where there is available room.  I've looked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/how-to-set-the-core-dump-file-location-and-name), but the answers seem to require sudo, and apply to all accounts.  I need something that will work without root access, and applies only to my account.

Comment: I had a bit of a google on this and concluded (like yourself) that it can't be done. (But they said that heavier than air flight was impossible so I'm prepared to be corrected)

It may be that it's a security thing - dumps are not encrypted and could contain passwords etc. So the sysadmin can control where dumps are located and who can read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/sbin/sysctl kernel.core_pattern` without root access to view the current core file naming pattern.

If the pattern does not begin with a `/` character, the core file will be created relative to the current working directory of the program dumping the core. So if your program is at `$HOME/myprogram`, do this:

```
cd /location/with/enough/space/and/writable/for/you
$HOME/myprogram
```

Now the core dump should be generated in the desired location and not in $HOME.